# Sinatra: NameError at '/route', undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nameerror, ruby-datamapper

I'm trying to build an admin backend for a cms website.

this is the structure of my application

```
├── app.rb
├── Gemfile
├── models
│   └── models.rb
├── routes
│   └── routes.rb
└── views
    ├── categories.erb
    ├── # ... other view files
```

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'digest'

enable :sessions

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'mysql://username:password@localhost/database')
require './models/models.rb' 
require './routes/routes.rb'
DataMapper.finalize
```

**models.rb**

```
class Category
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,         Serial
  property :name,       String

  has n, :posts
end
# other model definitons
```

I've defined a `categories` route inside my **routes.rb**

```
...
get '/categories' do 
    @categories = Category.all
    erb :categories
end 
...
```

Contents of view (`categories.erb`) file.

```
                #table headers   
                <tbody>
                <% @categories.each do |c| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= c.id %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= c.name %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= с.posts.count %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= c.posts(:order => [:updated_at.desc]).first.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
                </tbody>
```

When I browse to `/categories` route, server spits this error

```
NameError at /categories
undefined local variable or method `с' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x0000000284bc08>
```

I have not faced such problem before. And really don't know what is going on.

The problem probably is not with application structure (the require sequences inside app.rb) because, before `get '/categories'` I've defined a `post '/login'` route which checks user inputs against database records. And it works as I want.

```
post '/login' do 
    email = params[:email]
    pwd = params[:password]

    user = Author.first(:email=>email)

    if user.nil?
        redirect to ('/register')
    elsif !user.nil?
        if Digest::MD5.hexdigest(pwd) == user.password
        ... #and so on
```

**UPDATE**

I'm listing other table/models with same methods, and all of them works as i expected, but categories.

```
other routes  
get '/articles' do 
    @articles = Post.all(:is_blog_post => false)
    erb :site_articles
end
##blog articles
get '/blogposts' do 
    @barticles = Post.all(:is_blog_post => true)
    erb :blog_articles
end
#users
get '/admin_users' do
    @admins = Author.all(:is_admin=>true)
    erb :admin_users 
end

#bloggers
get '/bloggers' do
    @bloggers = Author.all(:is_admin=>false)
    erb :blog_users 
end
```

and corresponding view files
**site articles**

```
            <tbody>
            <% @articles.each do |art| %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.title %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.author.full_name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.category.name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.featured? ? "Yes" : "No" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
```

**blog articles**

```
            <tbody>
            <% @barticles.each do |art| %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.title %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.author.full_name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.category.name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.updated_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= art.featured? ? "Yes" : "No" %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
```

**admins**

```
            <tbody>
            <% @admins.each do |admin| %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= admin.full_name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= admin.email %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= !admin.twitter.nil? ? admin.twitter : "N/A" %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= !admin.facebook.nil? ? admin.facebook : "N/A" %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= !admin.phone.nil? ? admin.phone : "N/A" %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= admin.posts.count %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% end %>
            </tbody>
```

**bloggers**

```
                <tbody> 
                <% @bloggers.each do |blogger| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= blogger.full_name %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= blogger.email %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= !blogger.twitter.nil? ? blogger.twitter : "N/A" %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= !blogger.facebook.nil? ? blogger.facebook : "N/A" %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= !blogger.phone.nil? ? blogger.phone : "N/A" %>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%= blogger.posts.count %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </tbody>
```

Comment: does it give a line number?

Comment: yes, `file: categories.erb location: block (2 levels) in singleton class line: 28`  which corresponds to `<%= с.posts.count %>` 
the interesting is, i am able to list users with the same method inside another view file, but when attempting to list categories, program crashes. terminal output for the same script
 `> c.posts.count (# in newline)
 => 3 `

Comment: Try running in terminal `irb app.rb`, then try the command `var = Catagories.all.posts`. Then try `var.count`. Please tell me what happens

Comment: before trying it,  let me ask, `Category.all` will return an array which will include instances of `Category` class. I don't think this array will be able to respond `posts` method without errors.

Comment: You are doing that above: if `c = Catagories.all` then you are saying `Catagorey.all.posts.count`

Comment: maybe you've missed the iteration part. i've written` <% @categories.each do |c| %>` then for a single `c` instance, i called some attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve somehow got an odd character in your source. That’s not a “normal” latin `c` in the line `<%= с.posts.count %>`, it’s [U+0441, CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0441/index.htm). It just looks like a latin `c`.

To fix it just delete the character and re-write it with a normal `c`.

Comment: I thought something like this could explain what you see, so I copied the line into irb, and then called `bytes` on it to check. Do you know how it got there – are you using Cryillic script elsewhere?

Comment: yes, when i need need to write something in russian, i use cyrillic layout. and this picture may explain the situation. http://winrus.com/std_ru.gif :)
C and С use same key.